# How to get bitset OR with different bitset sizes

Tags: c++, binary, bit, bitset

When I use,

```
  std::bitset<5> op1 (std::string("01001"));
  std::bitset<5> op2 (std::string("10011"));

  std::cout << (op1|=op2) << std::endl;
```

everything is fine obviously.

But my question is, how can I use OR operation using two different sized 'std::bitset's?
Such as,

```
  std::bitset<11> op1 (std::string("101110011"));
  std::bitset<5> op2 (std::string("01001"));

  std::cout << (op1|=op2) << std::endl;
```

I can't compile this code in VS 2012. What have I missed here? Can't I use different sized bitsets for OR operations (and XOR as well)? Is this a platform specific problem?

Comment: Consider doing `a |= b` where the number of bits in `a` is less than in `b`. Now `a` would need to change its size, changing its type, which causes big problems. Now it could work if `a` was at least as big as `b`, but is it really worth the inconsistency? For something smaller like this, it's simple enough to convert them to integral types and OR those.

Comment: @chris Yes I understand. But in my example size of a (op1) is greater than b (op2). Which means the result should be sized of a's size. Correct? If so, it doesn't need to change a's size. So no type change will be there (in this example). But on the other way around, yes your point matters. We can't ask first operand to change its size. From my point of view, compiler should understand the sizes prior to complain us about size problems.

Comment: Sure, but don't you think it could be a little bit [astonishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Least_Astonishment) for it not to be symmetrical?

Comment: @chris That's a valid point too.

Comment: It's always possible this never came up (and there are the other operators to consider as well), but I'd like to think there's a specific decision as to why they're not like that. The reason would be too far back for me to have a good chance of finding it if it exists. Still, can't hurt to try one possible explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interface doesn't support this directly. You could construct a temporary bitset instead:

```
// assuming op1 is larger
op1 |= std::bitset<op1.size()>(op2.to_ullong())
```

If the larger bitset's value wouldn't fit in a `unsigned long long`, youl could call `to_string` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You might add customized operators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <limits>

namespace BitsetOperators {
namespace Detail {
    template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B, bool Less = A < B>
    struct Evaluate
    {
        static_assert(
               A <= std::size_t(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits)
            && B <= std::size_t(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits),
            "The bitset does not fit into an unsigned long long");

        typedef std::bitset<A> value_type;

        static value_type op_or(std::bitset<A> a, const std::bitset<B>& b) {
            return a |= value_type(b.to_ullong());
        }

        static value_type op_and(std::bitset<A> a, const std::bitset<B>& b) {
            return a &= value_type(b.to_ullong());
        }

        static value_type op_xor(std::bitset<A> a, const std::bitset<B>& b) {
            return a ^= value_type(b.to_ullong());
        }

        static bool op_eq(const std::bitset<A>& a, std::bitset<B> b) {
            return a.to_ullong() == b.to_ullong();
        }
    };

    template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
    struct Evaluate<A, B, true>
    {
        static_assert(
               A <= std::size_t(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits)
            && B <= std::size_t(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits),
            "The bitset does not fit into an unsigned long long");

        typedef std::bitset<B> value_type;

        static value_type op_or(const std::bitset<A>& a, std::bitset<B> b) {
            return b |= value_type(a.to_ullong());
        }

        static value_type op_and(const std::bitset<A>& a, std::bitset<B> b) {
            return b &= value_type(a.to_ullong());
        }

        static value_type op_xor(const std::bitset<A>& a, std::bitset<B> b) {
            return b ^= value_type(a.to_ullong());
        }

        static bool op_eq(const std::bitset<A>& a, std::bitset<B> b) {
            return b.to_ullong() == a.to_ullong();
        }
    };
} // namespace Detail


/// Operator A | B: The resulting bitset has the maximal size of A and B.
template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
inline typename Detail::Evaluate<A, B>::value_type
operator | (const std::bitset<A>& a, const std::bitset<B>& b) {
    return Detail::Evaluate<A, B>::op_or(a, b);
}

/// Operator A & B: The resulting bitset has the maximal size of A and B.
template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
inline typename Detail::Evaluate<A, B>::value_type
operator & (const std::bitset<A>& a, const std::bitset<B>& b) {
    return Detail::Evaluate<A, B>::op_and(a, b);
}

/// Operator A ^ B: The resulting bitset has the maximal size of A and B.
template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
inline typename Detail::Evaluate<A, B>::value_type
operator ^ (const std::bitset<A>& a, const std::bitset<B>& b) {
    return Detail::Evaluate<A, B>::op_xor(a, b);
}

/// Operator A == B
template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
inline bool operator == (const std::bitset<A>& a, const std::bitset<B>& b) {
    return Detail::Evaluate<A, B>::op_eq(a, b);
}

/// Operator A != B
template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
inline bool operator != (const std::bitset<A>& a, const std::bitset<B>& b) {
    return ! (a == b);
}

}  // namespace BitsetOperators


// Test
// ====

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    using namespace BitsetOperators;
    std::bitset<11> op1 (std::string("101110011"));
    std::bitset<5> op2 (std::string("01001"));
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << (op1 | op2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (op1 & op2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (op1 ^ op2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (op1 == op2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (op1 != op2) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using namespace std;

template <size_t startN, size_t endN>
bitset<endN> convert(bitset<startN> start)
{
    const size_t minBits = (startN < endN) ? startN : endN;
    const size_t min64Bits = (minBits - 1) / 64 + 1;
    bitset<endN> result;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < min64Bits; n++)
    {
        result <<= 64;
        result |= start.to_ullong();
        start >>= 64;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::bitset<11> op1 (std::string("101110011"));
    std::bitset<5> op2 (std::string("01001"));
    std::cout << (op1|=convert<5, 11>(op2));
}
```

You could use this function to convert if you may have more than 64 bits in your bitsets.